# Aws Cognito, remove username/password login and login only using social networking sites

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Aws Cognito, I have configured the option to sign in using Facebook and Google. Can we remove the normal authentication using a username and password?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the cognito user pool in the AWS console and click on the App client settings link, then uncheck cognito user pool, then it will only display the other idenity provider buttons without username and password fields

[image: client app settings]

[image: cognito sign in screen]